# How do I drop a table and reclaim the space in Cassandra 2.0?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

There are all sorts of conflicting methods on the internet to drop a table and reclaim the space in Cassandra 2.0. Some say drop, then delete the data off of disk manually, others say truncate and then drop. Most of the pages are actually about 1.0/1.1/1.2

If I have a table on a Cassandra 2.0.x host with all the nodes up, how do I drop the table AND delete all the data at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2.0 Best solution

```
Truncate
Drop keyspace
Remove folder from disk
```

The truncate is to attempt to avoid DROP/RECREATE issues and zombie data coming back. In any case once you've dropped a keyspace it's best not to reuse that name. A fix for DROP/RECREATE is coming in 2.1.

Comment: Confirmed. I was hoping there was a nicer way that didn't require manual cleanup.

Comment: You could always write a feature request ticket on the Jira, although I think most people like having the snapshots still there on the disk for extra "confirmation" when they delete :)